# Lost network access after updating (22.04.1)

Tags: networking, server, updates, network-manager, ethernet

I have a computer that I use as a home server that runs ubuntu server. Prior to this the last time the computer was updated was around 1 week ago. Today (2022/09/25) I performed an update and lost the ability to remotely connect to the computer.

When trying to ping from the effected computer I get the message "Destination Host Unreachable" and the computer in no longer contactable/visable on the network. When running a comand such as
`cnmcli device status` the ethernet device appears and with the command `ip a` the device has it's assigned static ip address. I have restarted my router and computer and have reseated ethernet wires to no effect.

For context: network devices on the server are managaed by the following NetPlan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  render: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp3: false
      addresses: [192.168.0.50/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
      enp4s0f0:
        addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
      enp4s0f1:
        addresses: [192.168.0.200/24]
  bridges:
    br100:
      addresses: [192.168.100.1/24]
      interfaces: [ vlan100 ]
  vlans:
    vlan100:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 100
      link: enp4s0f0
```

If there is any other details I'm happy to provide. Thank you for your time and patience.

---

Edit 1:
Netplan has been updated with local IP addresses.

The network has a single router that hands out DHCP address, the 3 IP addressees associated with the computer on the network are reserved to prevent conflicts with other devices.

The following message is periodicaly apearing on the cli, I don't know how relevent it is but I'm adding it in case it helps:

```
[xxx.xxxxxx] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: Reset adapter
```

where "x" is the time in seconds since the computer turned on.

Comment: It is OK to show full private IP addresses as they are unable to be routed so there is no way that someone is going to get direct access to them from the internet.  Do you have a separate router on your network that is handing out DHCP addresses?  And if so, have you given the static IPs a reservation in the router so that they are not given out to any other devices causing IP conflicts?  Please update your question with details.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Terrance, thank you for replying. I have added the requested details as well as a message I have noticed is appearing on the cli.

Comment: I guess it is entirely possible that a connection that keeps getting reset might be causing an issue.  Which one of the 3 IPs are you trying to connect on?  Maybe do a `sudo lshw -C network` and post the output into your question.  I have seen before where the RTL8169 driver was loading on a RTL8168 card and was extremely flaky.  But anything right now would be complete guessing.